# Edit multiple values in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to edit two columns using ajax and php.My code currently edits one values(name) in my table and saves it to my database.When i add the second  variable (p) my ajax call it updates both columns p and y with the same value.How do i edit the third value and assign it a different value from y.I want the two different columns to have different values in my db(columns:name and capacity)

This code edits and updates two values:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
        $('.xedit').editable();     
        $(document).on('click','.editable-submit',function(){
            var x = $(this).closest('td').children('span').attr('id');
            var y = $('.input-sm').val();
            var z = $(this).closest('td').children('span');
            $.ajax({
                url: "process.php?id="+x+"&data="+y,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(s){
                    if(s == 'status'){
                    $(z).html(y);}
                    if(s == 'error') {
                    alert('Error Processing your Request!');}
                },
                error: function(e){
                    alert('Error Processing your Request!!');
                }
            });
        });
});
</script>
```

And this is what i tried to edit three values:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
        $('.xedit').editable();     
        $(document).on('click','.editable-submit',function(){
            var x = $(this).closest('td').children('span').attr('id');
            var y = $('.input-sm').val();
            var p = $('.input-sm').val();
            var z = $(this).closest('td').children('span');
            $.ajax({
                url: "process.php?id="+x+"&data="+y+"&capacity="+y,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(s){
                    if(s == 'status'){
                    $(z).html(y);
                    $(z).html(p);}
                    if(s == 'error') {
                    alert('Error Processing your Request!');}
                },
                error: function(e){
                    alert('Error Processing your Request!!');
                }
            });
        });
});
</script>
```

And heres my php file(process.php)

```
    <?php
include("connect.php");
if
    ($_GET['id'],$_GET['capacity'] and $_GET['data'])
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $data = $_GET['data'];
    $capacity = $_GET['capacity'];
    if(mysqli_query($con,"update mytable set name='$data',capacity='$data' where id='$id'")){

        echo "success";
    }

else{
echo 'failed';
}

}
?>
```

And my table in index.php

```
 <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from mytable");
                    $i=0;
                    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                    {
                        if($i%2==0) $class = 'even'; else $class = 'odd';

                        echo'<tr class="'.$class.'">

                            <td><span class= "xedit external-event bg-brown" id="'.$fetch['id'].'">'.$fetch['name'].'</span></td>

                            <td><span class= "xedit external-event bg-brown" id="'.$fetch['id'].'">'.$fetch['capacity'].'</span></td>

                        </tr>';                         
                    }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: your just typo capacity=$data look this line and change it to capacity=$capacity : if(mysqli_query($con,"update mytable set name='$data',capacity='$capacity' where id='$id'"))

Comment: never seen this kind of IF condition if($_GET['id'],$_GET['capacity'] and $_GET['data']) . it should be if
    ($_GET['id'] && $_GET['capacity'] && $_GET['data'])

Comment: @JYoThI  im still learning.

Answer (score 1):

1) your just typo error : `capacity=$data` look this line and change it to `capacity=$capacity` :

```
if(mysqli_query($con,"update mytable set name='$data',capacity='$capacity' where id='$id'"))
```

2) And take look in If condition too .finally your code should be like this .

```
        <?php

        include("connect.php");
        if($_GET['id'] && $_GET['capacity'] && $_GET['data'])
        {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $data = $_GET['data'];
            $capacity = $_GET['capacity'];
            if(mysqli_query($con,"update mytable set name='$data',capacity='$capacity' where id='$id'"))
            {

                echo "success";
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'failed';
            }

        }

        ?>
```

Comment: Great.What about the x and y values in the ajax,do they remain the same.Considering x is the value of data and y is the append

Comment: url: "process.php?id="+x+"&data="+y+"&capacity="+y,    why data and capacity have same value y  ??

Comment: first of all alert the x y p and know that your getting right values or not ?

Comment: i fixed the x y and z issue.il edit it in the question

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your sql query. As you  not passing correct parameters.
Please see below code.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$data = $_GET['data'];
$capacity = $_GET['capacity'];

// Check Sql
$query = "update mytable set name='$data',capacity='$capacity' where id='$id'";
if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){

  echo "success";
} else{
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: ive rectified that error.Im still getting both columns updating with the same data

Comment: Please see this 
var y = $('.input-sm').val();
var p = $('.input-sm').val();
var z = $(this).closest('td').children('span');
 $.ajax({
                url: "process.php?id="+x+"&data="+y+"&capacity="+y,

in above the value of y and p are looking same and the url you are creating in that you passing data and capacity both with value `y'. So, on server end it will update same value to both columns.

there is some problem in client side. seems `y` and `p` both pointing to same html element so getting same value. Can you check and see

Comment: ok,thanks,i changed this...but the row columns still update with the same value.I did this: var x = $(this).closest('td').children('span').attr('id');
   var y = $('.input-sm').val();
            var p = $('.input-sm').val();
   var z = $(this).closest('td').children('span');                       url: "process.php?id="+x+"&data="+y+"&capacity="+p,

Comment: There is no difference in line var y = $('.input-sm').val(); var p = $('.input-sm').val();  So, of course y and p going to have same value. 
as Y and p are pointing to same html element and fetching same data.

Comment: i dont think the issue here is my php,i think its the ajax calls.Ive tried all the different insert queries i can think of but i still get both capacity and name updating with the same value

Comment: not sure either you read above comment properly or not.....
var y and var p both are pointing to same html element so they will always give same value.... nothing wrong in php side its client side issue before ajax.

Comment: Yes i did.Do you perhaps have a solution to the p and y pointing to the same html element,considering all the html is using span and tr,but obviosly seperate rows.I tried this to no effect:var x = $(this).closest('td').children('span').attr('id');                 var p = $(this).closest('td').children('span').attr('capacity');